# When computing distances between 2 vector layers - getting window of analysis right size

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, distance, raster-conversion

In QGIS I have a big island (Britain). There are lots of rivers inland, but not many at the coasts. The rivers were originally vector layers. I converted them to Raster (by burning them with the value of 1). The image attached shows the options I put in. This gives a black square over some of the island; it does not reach the coast because the rivers are all inland (or perhaps because I did not specify) I want the black square to cover the whole island.

- How would I specify that?

image: https://ibb.co/cfR2QG

Answer (score 2):

When you use the Rasterize (Vector to Raster), you need to specify the extent of the output raster based on the extent of the island polygon coverage. By default  the rasterize tool uses the extent of the input layer, and to override that you need to use this expression as additional parameter:

```
-te xmin ymin xmax ymax
```

For example, I have an internal line inside a polygon layer:

[image]

- Go to the `Layer Properties` of the polygon layer (the islands in your case) `-> Metadata -> Scroll down until you see the Extents`
- Copy `xMin,yMin` and `xMax,yMax` values and paste them in text editor
- Using Rasterize (Vector to Raster) tool from `Processing toolbox -> GDAL/OGR -> [GDAL] Conversion -> Rasterize (Vector to Raster)`, expand `Advanced Parameters`
- Under Additional creation parameters [optional] paste the extent from the text editor into this section (don't forget to add `-te` and remove the comma between `xMin yMin` and `xMax yMax` as you can see in the image below:

[image]

Here is the output covering the entire polygon extent:

[image]

Comment: This worked (though I had to merge the Britain 'square' and the original 'square' around the rivers. TY!

Comment: You are welcome. If it solved your problem, please accept the answer so that it can help others.